# How to identify the actual Unicode characters from the bytes when reading a UTF-8 file using Ascii decoding

Tags: c, utf-8, char, byte, ascii

I'm reading a `UTF-8` file using `fread()` - [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/).

The file can contain some Unicode characters. I want to identify cases where some specific characters were in the file.

For example, I chose `✇ (0x2707, 9991)`, and when I read it from the file, I'm getting three characters - `â (226), œ (156) ‡ (135)`.

How would I go about understanding the original Unicode characters from these three bytes? I tried to construct a single integer from them and got 14851207. If I split 9991 to two bytes I'll get 39, 7.

Note that I could of course change my implementation and read a `wchar` with Unicode supporting library function, but its legacy code that cannot really be changed.

Comment: Unicode defines its methods of encoding and decoding. Look into those, the Unicode Standard is free to all.

Comment: Search for `libiconv`. It's probably already installed on your system, but in any case, it's [freely available](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Comment: Thanks. looking at this conversion site for example https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ , seems that the Ascii values I'm getting are "UTF-8 code units", so just need to dig the open sources to find the decoding function of those

Comment: Text files by definition use only one encoding, for one character set, so your text file contains all Unicode characters. You might be getting three `char`s but not three "characters"; A UTF-8 code unit is one `char`; Any similiarity to ASCII is not relevant. In compiling your source code, if your source encoding is a Unicode encoding and your destination encoding is UTF-8, you could just compare with `"✇"`. If you to do processing by codepoints, you could convert to UTF-32, who's code units are identical to the codepoints.

Comment: @Mugen: "*seems that the Ascii values I'm getting are "UTF-8 code units"*" - yes.  "*so just need to dig the open sources to find the decoding function of those*" - yes, you should use a pre-existing Unicode library that handles UTF-8 for you. However, UTF-8 is easy to implement by hand. There are numerous posts on StackOverflow showing manual UTF-8 encoders/decoders that you can look at. You might also want to read up about UTF-8 on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the [Unicode standard](http://unicode.org), [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629), etc.